# Using Kinect 360 as 3D Scanner

Tags: 3d-models, scanning

I would like to use my old Xbox 360 Kinect as a scanner for 3D modeling and (hopefully) printing a few busts of friends/family members; however, my efforts have failed in each direction that I have taken. Has anyone had success with this,  and if so, how do I fix the issues that I am facing?

What I have done so far and the problems that I have had:

1. I have purchased a cable to supply 12V to the Kinect while also allowing USB to a PC.
2. I have installed the Kinect SDK as well as the Kinect Developers Toolkit on my Windows 10 Ultrabook.
3. I installed the Microsoft "3D Scan" app and the "Kinect Readiness" app (not the name, unsure of it at this point) provided by Microsoft.

**Issue: ** Neither Microsoft app detects the  Kinect when cable is plugged in. The Kinect's light slowly flashes green. Also, my cursor freezes when the Kinect is plugged in.

4. I checked the Hardware profiles and found a notification that I do  not have the drivers for the Kinect motor and that no suitable  drivers could be found. However, no other details about the Kinect showed up.
5. I uninstalled the SDK and developer toolkits and installed v1.7, ran them in compatibility mode (Windows 8) and same issues arose.
6. I then began looking into using a different program, found ReconstructMe. This too failed to detect the Kinect even when it was manually selected as the scanner.

Any ideas? I also have a Linux Mint laptop that I will happily use for these efforts if I knew what software to capture the 3D scan with. It seems that there are several driver options out there, just unsure of what to use besides that. It seems that Blender can be used for some motion capture with Kinect; however, I am unsure of how this relates to my goals.

Comment: Have you looked into Skanect?

Comment: In the past I've used the openkinect freenect Python wrapper in Linux to stream the Kinect's structured light sensor's depth data throught a TCP socket into an application called Blender (using its internal python API) which then received the socket data and rendered a pointcloud of vertices in the viewport, each vertex along the XY coordinate plane had its Z coordinate as a function of the depth pixel intensity. Blender would allow you to also write a custom surface reconstruction algorithm (if you desired), or you could export the cloud to a 3rd party application.

Comment: Unfortunately, the complexity of this option is limiting. I would like to implement this with my middle school students. Are there any simpler/streamlined solutions?

Comment: For what it's worth, I had this set up (a few years ago) with a very minimal amount of fuss, using http://brekel.com/kinect-3d-scanner/
I made a few scans of household objects, friends, and then got distracted by some other shiny thing. Hopefully, the page continues to be a good resource. Figured I'd share it just in case.

Comment: I think you're just slightly off with your SDK. I'm fairly certain the most stable version for **XBox 360 Kinect** on PC is **V1.6.0**. Which works fine for scanning, but lacks in some of the other functionality like skeletal tracking and faster facial recognition.

Comment: I think professional scanners have better quality. In this video I watched, you can see the quality https://youtu.be/cEJHXDsYeww

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the same setting old kinect (but for PC - actually with power supply and usb-cable) plug to my surface windows10.

After some troubles, it works now ;-)

The mentioned MS 3D scan and kinect readiness wont work. It is supposed for the new kinect2 model, because of the new driver. Best you deinstall both. Even the drivers and SDKs.

You need Kinect for Windows v1.8 for the old kinect. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40278

RecFusion is a software for using a single or multiple depth cams for getting 3d models. It works quite good with my kinect. It costs 99euros.  http://recfusion.net/index.php/en/download

Comment: I was hoping to use the Kinect as a way of saving money. So unfortunately, this option is a bit over my price-range. Thank you for the help though.